# awk script to process 400 .txt files

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, awk

I have a nice .awk script that takes the 2nd $2 value and prints it. Because the data in the .txt files only go down 8192 lines, any lines after that are irrelevant (the script takes care of that.) I have 400+ .tst files that need to have the same thing done and have the ouput's placed into a single file. So how would I go through every .tst file in the current directory? I tried piping the cat output to a single line version of the script but it only processed the first file. Any suggestions?

```
BEGIN{
}
{
print $2 "\n";
if (NR==8192)
        exit;
}
END {
    print NR "\n";
}
```

Comment: I suggest omitting the empty BEGIN section, especially here on SO.

Comment: `print $2 "\n"` will print an empty line after each output line, is that really what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work -

```
awk 'FNR<=8192{ print $2 }' *.tst > finalfile
```

Comment: my bad, sorry. FNR is correct! I misunderstood the question! +1

Comment: Works great, I was just trying to get it to skip the first line in each file with: "awk 'FNR<=8192 && FNR!=1 { print $2 }' *.tst > finalfile". Could not get that to work so far.

Comment: Try this: `awk 'FNR>1 && FNR<=8192 { print $2 }' *.tst > finalfile`

Answer (score 1):

Just glob all the `.tst` files in the current directory and redirect the output to `outfile`:

```
$ awk 'FNR<=8192{print $2"\n";next}{print FNR"\n";nextfile}' *.tst > outfile
```

Comment: This will only process the first file, you want `FNR` instead of `NR` and replace the `exit` with something else.

Comment: Gawk has `nextfile` for this.

Comment: @tripleee pah, what was I thinking!?

Comment: Maybe `print FNR` in the last block, too?